# __getitem__ and no brackets (or simultaneously with __get__)

Tags: python

I am wondering whether there is a workaround to this. I created a class that contains several array properties, that are stored in disc by means of Pandas' HDFStore. Below there is a simplified version of that class, that contains only one of such properties:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore',category=pd.io.pytables.PerformanceWarning)
class Data(object):   
    class FileArray(object):
        def __init__(self, filename, key):
            self.filename = filename
            self.key = key

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):         
            print('get')
            try:
                store = pd.HDFStore(self.filename, mode='r')
                array = store[self.key].values
                store.close()
            except KeyError:
                store.close()
                array = None
            return(array)

        def __set__(self, instance, array):
            print('set')
            if array != None:
                store = pd.HDFStore(self.filename)
                store[self.key] = pd.DataFrame(array)
                store.close()

        def __getitem__(self, pos):
            print('get item')
            if type(pos) != tuple or len(pos) != 2:
                raise IndexError('Index must be a tuple of length 2')
            y, x = pos
            try:
                store = pd.HDFStore(self.filename, mode='r')
                array = store[self.key].values
                store.close()
                value = array[y][x]
            except KeyError:
                store.close()
                value = None
            return value

        def __setitem__(self, pos, value):
            print('set_item')
            if type(pos) != tuple or len(pos) != 2:
                raise IndexError('Index must be a tuple of length 2')
            x, y = pos
            try:
                store = pd.HDFStore(self.filename)
                array = store[self.key].values
                array[x,y] = value
                store[self.key] = pd.DataFrame(array)
                store.close()
            except KeyError:
                store.close()

    # Class data definition
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        setattr(self.__class__, 'array', self.FileArray(self.filename, 'array') )
```

If **I remove the __get__ class**, everything seems to be working as expected:

```
>>> data = Data('file')
>>> data.array = np.random.rand(10,10)
set
>>> data.array[0,0]
get item
0.82546762173073829
>>> data.array[0,0] = 10
set_item
>>> data.array[0,0]
get item
10.0
```

However, I can not get the array by removing the brackets:

```
>>> data.array
<__main__.FileArray object at 0x09507D30>
```

If I include the `__get__` method, then data.array works as expected. However, from that moment on, `__get__` is always invoked, even if I use the brackets. Therefore, I can not use the brackets to modify individual elements of the array stored in disk:

```
>>> data = Data('file')
>>> data.array = np.random.rand(10,10)
set
>>> data.array[0,0]
get
0.38273033820794067
>>> data.array[0,0] = 10
get
>>> data.array[0,0]
get
0.38273033820794067
```

Is there any way I can either:

- use `__get__` simultaneously in the same class together with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`?
- or, have `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` invoked, without using brackets?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Why do you want the class to be a descriptor; you're not using it like one.

Comment: My aim is to have a class with a set of array properties. I should be able to operate with the arrays as if they were normal numpy arrays, but having them actually stored in disk. Any value change should be immediately stored into disk.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to use a regular `@property` but have it return something that provides the array interface while backing it with your store. Trying to cram both into one object is bound to be a headache!

Comment: I don't see how to implement an array interface without a `__get__` method... and as soon as I implement that method, I will be facing the same problem.

Comment: Numpy's arrays don't implement `__get__`, that's part of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol). Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Because using the descriptor protocol is the only way I know to implement bracket access.

Comment: What do you mean by *"bracket access"*? `obj[...]` is implemented by `__[get|set|del]item__` and `obj(...)` by `__call__`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91838/discussion-between-pablo-suau-and-jonrsharpe).